# how to hold `params[:search]` value even after page gets load in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In views:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels',:search=>params[:search] do %>                 
  <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => 'search-box', :required => true,:placeholder=>'Type Your City Name(Bhubaneswar,Cuttack)'%>                 
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch',class: "btn-orange",:method=>'get' %>             
<%end%>
```

In controller:

```
@hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%").includes(:offers)
```

The search is working fine but the problem is that when i load the page again it is showing all the values in the database, filter is not working.

I think i can solve this problem by passing `params[:search]` to the URL, but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Marek can u help me out.

Comment: @Jack I've edited and improved your formatting..just accept it

Comment: @Ali Suggested edits are reviewed by other users, not the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `:method => 'get'` from `submit_tag` to `form_tag` line:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels',:search=>params[:search], method: :get do %>
```

Comment: To what action in your controller is this request going ? How is the request coming through if you check the logs ? GET or POST ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels', :action => "action_name", method: :get do %>                  
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'search-box', :required => true,:placeholder=>'Type Your City Name(Bhubaneswar,Cuttack)'%>                 
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch',class: "btn-orange",:method=>'get' %>             
<%end%>
```